# tortoisesvn error running context an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new in SVN and when I tried to import/add or commit my project on it I got this message

```
error running context an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
```

I can checkout any project from this server without any issues. 
I'm using TortoiseSVN version 1.9.7 "latest one"
any advise